# Exception while sending SOAP request message : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!'

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have implemented SAAJ API of Java to create a SOAP request message and send it to the Endpoint URL. But I'm receiving following error while sending the SOAP message:

`javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'd' (code 100) after '<!' (malformed comment?) at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,3] at org.apache.axis2.saaj.SOAPConnectionImpl.call(SOAPConnectionImpl.java                                                                                        :209)`

The SOAP message that i send is :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<soapenv:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<addMembers xmlns="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd">
<groupName xmlns="">
<name>FI Index</name>
<domainName>SPOTFIRE</domainName>
</groupName>

<memberNames xmlns:q1="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd" xmlns="" xsi:type="q1:UserName">
<name>UserID</name>
<domainName>SPOTFIRE</domainName>
</memberNames>


</addMembers>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could you please suggest me what could be causing the error ? Also below is the WSDL file of the target application:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:ns1="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/faults.xsd" name="UserDirectoryService" targetNamespace="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd" xmlns:ns1="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/common.xsd" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/userdir.xsd" version="1.0">

  <xs:import namespace="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/common.xsd"/>

  <xs:element name="addMembers" type="tns:addMembers"/>

  <xs:element name="addMembersResponse" type="tns:addMembersResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="createGroup" type="tns:createGroup"/>

  <xs:element name="createGroupResponse" type="tns:createGroupResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="createUser" type="tns:createUser"/>

  <xs:element name="createUserResponse" type="tns:createUserResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getAllGroups" type="tns:getAllGroups"/>

  <xs:element name="getAllGroupsResponse" type="tns:getAllGroupsResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getGroupById" type="tns:getGroupById"/>

  <xs:element name="getGroupByIdResponse" type="tns:getGroupByIdResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getGroupByName" type="tns:getGroupByName"/>

  <xs:element name="getGroupByNameResponse" type="tns:getGroupByNameResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getImmediateGroups" type="tns:getImmediateGroups"/>

  <xs:element name="getImmediateGroupsResponse" type="tns:getImmediateGroupsResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getMembers" type="tns:getMembers"/>

  <xs:element name="getMembersResponse" type="tns:getMembersResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getUserById" type="tns:getUserById"/>

  <xs:element name="getUserByIdResponse" type="tns:getUserByIdResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="getUserByName" type="tns:getUserByName"/>

  <xs:element name="getUserByNameResponse" type="tns:getUserByNameResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="isMember" type="tns:isMember"/>

  <xs:element name="isMemberResponse" type="tns:isMemberResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="removeMembers" type="tns:removeMembers"/>

  <xs:element name="removeMembersResponse" type="tns:removeMembersResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="removePrincipals" type="tns:removePrincipals"/>

  <xs:element name="removePrincipalsResponse" type="tns:removePrincipalsResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="searchGroups" type="tns:searchGroups"/>

  <xs:element name="searchGroupsResponse" type="tns:searchGroupsResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="searchUsers" type="tns:searchUsers"/>

  <xs:element name="searchUsersResponse" type="tns:searchUsersResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setDisplayName" type="tns:setDisplayName"/>

  <xs:element name="setDisplayNameResponse" type="tns:setDisplayNameResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setEmail" type="tns:setEmail"/>

  <xs:element name="setEmailResponse" type="tns:setEmailResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setMembers" type="tns:setMembers"/>

  <xs:element name="setMembersResponse" type="tns:setMembersResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setName" type="tns:setName"/>

  <xs:element name="setNameResponse" type="tns:setNameResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setPassword" type="tns:setPassword"/>

  <xs:element name="setPasswordResponse" type="tns:setPasswordResponse"/>

  <xs:element name="setUserEnabled" type="tns:setUserEnabled"/>

  <xs:element name="setUserEnabledResponse" type="tns:setUserEnabledResponse"/>

  <xs:complexType name="getImmediateGroups">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="PrincipalName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="domainName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="UserName">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:PrincipalName">
        <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="GroupName">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:PrincipalName">
        <xs:sequence/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getImmediateGroupsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="GroupPrincipal">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:SpotfirePrincipal">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="immutable" type="xs:boolean"/>
          <xs:element name="fixed" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType abstract="true" name="SpotfirePrincipal">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="ns1:GUID"/>
      <xs:element name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
      <xs:element name="displayName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType final="extension restriction" name="UserPrincipal">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:SpotfirePrincipal">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="enabled" type="xs:boolean"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getMembers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getMembersResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:SpotfirePrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getUserByName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" type="tns:UserName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getUserByNameResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:UserPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setUserEnabled">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" type="tns:UserName"/>
      <xs:element name="enabled" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setUserEnabledResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="createUser">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="username" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="domainName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="displayName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="createUserResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:UserPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setMembers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="memberNames" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setMembersResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getGroupById">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="ns1:GUID"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getGroupByIdResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="addMembers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="memberNames" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="addMembersResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setEmail">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setEmailResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setDisplayName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="displayName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setDisplayNameResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="searchUsers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="searchExpression" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="maxResults" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="searchUsersResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:UserPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="searchGroups">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="searchExpression" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="maxResults" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="searchGroupsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="isMember">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="isMemberResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="return" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="removePrincipals">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="principalNames" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="removePrincipalsResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="removeMembers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="memberNames" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="removeMembersResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getGroupByName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="tns:GroupName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getGroupByNameResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setName">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setNameResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getAllGroups">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="principalName" type="tns:PrincipalName"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getAllGroupsResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setPassword">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" type="tns:UserName"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="setPasswordResponse">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="createGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="groupName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="displayName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="createGroupResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:GroupPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getUserById">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="ns1:GUID"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="getUserByIdResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="tns:UserPrincipal"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/faults.xsd" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/faults.xsd">
  <xs:element name="FaultInfo" type="tns:FaultInfo"/>
  <xs:complexType name="FaultInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="errorCode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserDirectoryServiceException" nillable="true" type="tns:FaultInfo"/>
</xs:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://spotfire.tibco.com/ws/pub/2013/03/common.xsd" version="1.0">

  <xs:simpleType name="GUID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="setMembers">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setMembers" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getImmediateGroupsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getImmediateGroupsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setMembersResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setMembersResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removePrincipalsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:removePrincipalsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    <wsdl:part element="ns1:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getUserByNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getUserByNameResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getMembersResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getMembersResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setDisplayNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setDisplayNameResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setDisplayName">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setDisplayName" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="searchUsers">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:searchUsers" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="searchGroups">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:searchGroups" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="searchUsersResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:searchUsersResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="isMember">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:isMember" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getUserByIdResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getUserByIdResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="isMemberResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:isMemberResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getAllGroupsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getAllGroupsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setName">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setName" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="searchGroupsResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:searchGroupsResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getAllGroups">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getAllGroups" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setPassword">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setPassword" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getUserById">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getUserById" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getImmediateGroups">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getImmediateGroups" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addMembersResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:addMembersResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getMembers">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getMembers" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getUserByName">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getUserByName" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setUserEnabled">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setUserEnabled" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setEmailResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setEmailResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createUser">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createUser" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setUserEnabledResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setUserEnabledResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getGroupById">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getGroupById" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setPasswordResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setPasswordResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createGroupResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createGroupResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="addMembers">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:addMembers" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setEmail">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setEmail" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getGroupByNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getGroupByNameResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeMembersResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:removeMembersResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getGroupByIdResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getGroupByIdResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removePrincipals">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:removePrincipals" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createUserResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createUserResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="removeMembers">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:removeMembers" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getGroupByName">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getGroupByName" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="setNameResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:setNameResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="createGroup">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:createGroup" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="UserDirectoryService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getImmediateGroups">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getImmediateGroups" name="getImmediateGroups">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getImmediateGroupsResponse" name="getImmediateGroupsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getMembers">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getMembers" name="getMembers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getMembersResponse" name="getMembersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getUserByName">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getUserByName" name="getUserByName">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getUserByNameResponse" name="getUserByNameResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="setUserEnabled">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:setUserEnabled" name="setUserEnabled">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:setUserEnabledResponse" name="setUserEnabledResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="createUser">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:createUser" name="createUser">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:createUserResponse" name="createUserResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="setMembers">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:setMembers" name="setMembers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:setMembersResponse" name="setMembersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getGroupById">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getGroupById" name="getGroupById">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getGroupByIdResponse" name="getGroupByIdResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="addMembers">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:addMembers" name="addMembers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:addMembersResponse" name="addMembersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="setEmail">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:setEmail" name="setEmail">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:setEmailResponse" name="setEmailResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="setDisplayName">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:setDisplayName" name="setDisplayName">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:setDisplayNameResponse" name="setDisplayNameResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="searchUsers">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:searchUsers" name="searchUsers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:searchUsersResponse" name="searchUsersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="searchGroups">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:searchGroups" name="searchGroups">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:searchGroupsResponse" name="searchGroupsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="isMember">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:isMember" name="isMember">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:isMemberResponse" name="isMemberResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removePrincipals">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:removePrincipals" name="removePrincipals">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:removePrincipalsResponse" name="removePrincipalsResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="removeMembers">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:removeMembers" name="removeMembers">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:removeMembersResponse" name="removeMembersResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="getGroupByName">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getGroupByName" name="getGroupByName">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getGroupByNameResponse" name="getGroupByNameResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault message="tns:UserDirectoryServiceException" name="UserDirectoryServiceException">
    </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

Comment: Well, the parser is correct in saying that `<!d` cannot appear legally in XML, the challenge is finding out where that sequence appears, and it's not anywhere in the code you've shown us, so the only thing we can tell you is that it's somewhere else. Sorry if that's unhelpful, but that's all that we can determine from the information given.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the reply. Yes you are right, i too tried to search where <!d is appearing but could not locate anything. Do you know how exactly it is decided what SOAP message is to be sent to the Endpoint? Is it created on the basis of WSDL file?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't help you with SOAP and WSDL.